# Errors when doing npm install

Tags: npm, npm-install

I've already installed Node.js in my machine. When I try `npm install`, the installation does not properly work for me. I get the following on my console:

Installed node version 14.15.1

Installed npm version 6.14.8

Installed angular cli version 11.2.3

And then some errors pop up. Here's a screenshot of my console:

[image]

Comment: You may accept the the answer if it works :)

Answer (score 1):

Any of the following methods might be useful for you:

**Method 1:** Clean cache & then perform an installation

```
npm cache clean --force
npm install
```

**Method 2:** Exclude `package-lock.json` file and perform an installation

```
npm install --no-package-lock
```

**Method 3:** Manually delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` file and then perform an installation

```
npm install
```

Comment: Method 3 worked for me. Do I need to include the package-lock.json file again to run the project?

Comment: Yes, for that run `npm install`. It should re-generate the package-lock.json file.